# Node.js node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Recently I saw a picture in the `CNode` community. The source is a picture of the founder of `Node` `ry` in a speech. But I don't understand what it means. Please answer the big God?

This map is to explain `Node.js node_modules` what problem? Does it mean that `Node.js` `modules` reference each other too deeply?

1. ..................Sun               `----------`
2. ....Neutron star      `----------------------`
3. .......Brack hole        `----------------------------------------`
4. node_modules      `--------------------------------------------------------`

HEAVIEST OBJECTS IN THE UNIVERSE

PS:Since you can't send pictures, use the figure above to replace。[Link:](https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000015198651)

Comment: first, is not wise to direct translate the question from other site like this, second i believe the comment on the link you show already provided answer for it

Comment: Because that question was what I asked, but I didn't get answers from there to convince me. And I don't want to jump to that site, but stackoverflow won't let me upload pictures.

Comment: what they said is correct, node_modules took a lot of dependencies which all been downloaded and store in your node_modules folder after you install the npm, it make the solution much more heavier than usual.

Comment: That is to say that the meaning of that figure is that the Node.js module is too dependent on the problem?

Comment: I will post an answer with the dependency issue for `node_module`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Node.js node_module` is heaviest object

Because of the dependency of **EVERY** single `npm module` you have install, it will be download all dependency and store into your `node_modules` folder.

Let have a simple example here.

You have a `npm module` module A which dependent on module B. Therefore the structure of your `node_modules` folder will be

```
node_modules
↳ moduleA
  ↳ node_modules
    ↳ moduleB
```

Now, you install another `npm module` module C which dependent on module A, and here comes the problem of the folder structure.

```
node_modules
↳ moduleA (duplicated)
  ↳ node_modules
    ↳ moduleB
↳ moduleC
  ↳ node_modules
    ↳ moduleA (duplicated)
      ↳ node_modules
        ↳ moduleB
```

As you can see the folder structure of your `npm module` dependency, it build up the folder size bigger and bigger. The more dependency you require the heavier the `node_module` you get.

Hope it help you to understand why it explain as the heaviest object